# Prevent dismissal of uialertController before text validation. Not working in ios 10 but work in ios 9

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, gesture

I defined a long gesture controller attached to a UIAlertcontroller view which run when i click on Ok button. When validation is false alert is not dismissed on ios 9.3 but in ios 10 is dismissed. I'm trying to figure out why is not working in ios 10

Set up of the gesture

```
   let gestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init()
    gestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.0
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.appendAlert(sender:)))
    alert.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

gesture target function definition

```
  func appendAlert(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, edit it into your question as text.

Comment: Alert is an UIAlert controller